# Salesforce as the subscriber from external event bus

Tags: platform-event, streaming-api, event-monitoring

We are doing some re-architecturing and want to use a centralized event bus for all applications across our company. So, we are changing the sync direction of several processes, which will potentially require salesforce to act as the subscriber in a pub/sub model (we are looking at using ESBs like Amazon MSK or CloudKarafka).

the issue is, I can't seem to find if this is actually possible with the streaming API/cometD other examples I've found. They all only seem to handle salesforce being the publisher, and we would need an explicit callout to an apex rest endpoint/platform event.

this is the closest thing I've found, but I don't want salesforce to be the blocker in the decision making process https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-salesforce/current/sobjects_sink/index.html

If this is possible in a more generic way is anyone able to just point me down the correct path?

Comment: kind of, I've seen this question, it basically says no you can't do it though, so was checking again. but it does seem like we're going to need some other integration in between our bus and salesforce. I think I see some things I didnt see before in the CometD.NetCore examples

Comment: Other than linked answer above, [Architect Decision Guides](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/#decision-guides) are your friends